# Cannot print the contents of Array using print_r( )

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am developing a `Wordpress` site that allows users to order `x` amounts of a particular product. I pass the data for the order around the site using a `cookie`.

Initially everything was working fine and when I called `print_r($orderArray)` the `array` containing the order items would display.

However, my code is no longer working, for some reason `$orderArray` is no longer an `array`. This code below will output `NOT ARRAY`

```
function process_order_form_handler() {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['order_cookie'])){
    json_encode($_COOKIE['order_cookie']);
    $orderArray = json_decode($_COOKIE['order_cookie'], true);  

    echo $orderArray;

    $orderTime = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
    $orderContent = "Order Request Code: " . $orderTime . "<br/>";
    $orderContent .= "===Order===" . "<br/>";

    //Loop through the Array and print data
    if(is_array($orderArray)){
    foreach($orderArray as $item){
        if(!array_key_exists('comment', $item)){
        $orderContent .= "Stock Code: " . $item['stockCode'] . " Qty: " . $item['quantity'] . "<br/>";
        }else{
        $orderContent .= "Comments: " . $item['comment'];
        }
    }
    }else{
        echo "NOT ARRAY";
    }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why, the only changes I made was by modifying my `form action` to the `permalink` of the post and then I check if the `POST` array exists, if it does I call a method contained in `functions-process-order.php` and thats when I run into problems.

Can anyone see why `$orderArray` is not being seen as an `array`?

Result of `var_dump($orderArray)`

```
string '[{\"stockCode\":\"CBL202659/A\",\"quantity\":\"3\"},{\"stockCode\":\"CBL201764\",\"quantity\":6},{\"comment\":\"\",\"quantity\":null},{\"comment\":\"\"},{\"comment\":\"\"},{\"comment\":\"\"},{\"comment\":\"vdcvcvcv\"},{\"comment\":\"\"}]' (length=237)
```

Result of `print_r($_COOKIE['order_cookie']);`

```
[{\"stockCode\":\"CBL202659/A\",\"quantity\":\"3\"},{\"stockCode\":\"CBL201764\",\"quantity\":6}]
```

Comment: My favorite snippet for displaying var content : <?php echo '<pre>',var_dump($var),'</pre>'; ?> and by the way, you're not assigning your encoded array ;)

Comment: `json_encode($_COOKIE['order_cookie']);` This line does nothing.

Comment: You might want to find another way to store the data, because cookies have a limit and should your client exceed it, the data will be truncated and you will get unexplained errors.

Answer (score 2):

you are encoding but not assigning to any variable, and trying to decode, change:

```
json_encode($_COOKIE['order_cookie']);
$orderArray = json_decode($_COOKIE['order_cookie'], true);
...
```

to

```
$encoded = json_encode($_COOKIE['order_cookie']);
$orderArray = json_decode($encoded, true);
echo json_last_error_msg(); //check if any error 
...
```

Comment: Still results in same problem

Comment: @Javacadabra what do you get when you print_r($_COOKIE['order_cookie']); ...?

Comment: no that results in `var_dump($orderArray);` displaying `null`

Comment: @Javacadabra try adding echo json_last_error_msg(); after json_decode() to see if there's any error

Comment: @Javacadabra try with print_r(json_decode(stripslashes($encoded), true));

Comment: No it did not work, When I add the array to the cookie I do this:     `$.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });` is there anything I might be doing wrong there? I just don't understand how all of a sudden my `array` is now a `string`

Comment: @Javacadabra try chaiging your JSON.stringify(productArray) to JSON.stringify({json: productArray}) .... and it should work..!

Comment: `string '{\"json\":[{\"stockCode\":\"CBL202659/A\",\"quantity\":\"3\"},{\"stockCode\":\"CBL201764\",\"quantity\":6},{\"comment\":\"\"}]}' (length=127)` - that is the output